# Spring boot userRepository.findAll() displaying too many times and causing stackoverflow error

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have this code but my output on my browser is not what i want

```
@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public @ResponseBody List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

Output:

```
[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users":[{"id":4,"firstName":"busayo","lastName":"amowe","email":"amoweolubusayo@gmail.com","password":"$2a$10$09kGDhlEp.Xmj0ocDjGLTO.03z.kGQKm2ZHcsNetDpH0r6m1rkVIu","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN","users"
```

Isn't it supposed to be printed once? It says StackOverFlow Error and my getJson function cannot display it. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency between the `user` and `user role` entities.

In order to return your response to the client, your `List<User>` has to be serialized. You have to tell Jackson how to handle cycles or it will fail with stack overflow exception.

```
public class User {

    @JsonBackReference
    public List<Role> roles;

    // ...       

}

public class Role {

    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<User> users;

    // ...       

}
```

For a Jackson tutorial regarding bidirectional relationships, see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: I'm glad! If the solution helped you, consider accepting the answer.